# Inline-block text not centering

Tags: html, css

I have this box and it has three inline-block text elements, The left and right text are working but the text in the middle isn't centred properly. [View here](https://jsfiddle.net/9sahhgn6/2/)

```css
div.row #banner {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  background-color: #FF9935;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

div.row #banner p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.row #banner .shordy {
  font-family: lato, serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

div.row #banner #hero {
  font-family: lato, serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inline1 {
  float: left;
}

#inline3 {
  float: right;
}

.banner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="banner">
    <p class="text-left inline-block shordy" id="inline1">We're On Your Side...</p>
    <span class="text-center" id="hero" style="text-align: center;">Welcome To Property Snagging Direct...</span>
    <p class="inline-block text-right shordy" id="inline3"><i>Your Independent, Specialist Property Inspectors</i></p>
  </div>
  <!-- text-center -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>
```

Please expand the results box so you can see what I'm talking about.

*** It's the "Welcome To Property Snagging Direct..." that not centered ***

Comment: Looks pretty centered to me. Browser issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: @anomaaly mayby he means that he want's the text centered regardless of the other texts width?

Comment: @JariFlederick yes

Comment: Ok, I added a class called .three. https://jsfiddle.net/cagvhpe5/

Comment: @anomaaly Thanks a lot it worked!

Comment: @Gulnoor added a display change to your span, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's centered in the free space between the two floating elements, you can see that if you shorten the text of the right one.

https://jsfiddle.net/ovv1utt4/1/

To avoid this you can center that element with this CSS:

```
#hero {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9onnmhtu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your span to 100% width of its parent if you want to center its contents. Right now, the span is only the width of the text itself - so it has no way to be centered to the actual parent.

Just add something like

```
span{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but someone else (@anomaaly) solved it while keeping the span inline

Comment: Glad you found your resolution.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also add inline-block to your hero span.

```
#hero {
  display: inline-block;
}
.three {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cagvhpe5/2/
I only added the background color and border so you can see the widths change as you expand. Anymore than that then you might want to use table displays.

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align` property you try to set to the `<span class="text-center" id="hero">` element works only for block elements (those with `display: block`) and affects their text and `inline-*` contents. So you should set it to the parent of this `span` (i.e. `<div id="banner">`) to get this `span` centered.

Also, your `inline-block` class does nothing for `#inline` and `#inline3` elements, since they are `float`ed, and the `float` property overrides the `display` setting (making them effectively `display: block`, but with special placement rules).